# How to get view modification date using SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to log the state of views in my Oracle DB. For each view I want to get it's text and the last modification date.

I successfully got view text by using the following query:

```
select text from ALL_VIEWS where upper(view_name) like upper(<view_name>);
```

In SQL Navigator I also can see the modification date for each view. Is it possible to get this date by SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User need to join to user_objects. Something like:

```
  select v.view_name, o.last_ddl_time, v.text
  from user_objects o
  join user_views v
    on v.view_name = o.object_name
  where v.view_name = upper( '&vname' )
```

Comment: thanks! It works for me! The only thing is that modification date is stored in `last_ddl_time` instead of `timestamp`